# order of growth of a counting function

Tags: complex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. For every $t>0$, define $n(t)=$ the number of $a_n$ satisfying the inequality $|a_n|\leq t$. We call $n(r)$ the counting function for the sequence. In the book "Lectures on entire functions" by Levin, i read that the order of growth of $n(r)$ is
$$\rho=\limsup_{r\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{log \ n(r)}{log \ r}$$
How can i understand/prove this formula?

Comment: It seems to be a definition of $\rho$ rather than some formula. Indeed, if $a_k = k$ then $n(k) = k$ and $\rho = \infty$

Comment: yes you are right, it is a definiton. In what follows, Levin shows that such an order of growth $\rho$ coincides with the convergence exponent of $\{a_n\}$, which is the inf of all $\lambda>0$ such that $\sum\frac{1}{|a_n|^{\lambda}}<+\infty$....but i can't understand the proof

Comment: If you know that $\log n(r)\sim \rho\log r$ for large $r$, then it means that $n(r)$ grows approximately as $r^\rho$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, the formula $$\rho=\limsup_{r\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log  n(r)}{\log  r}\tag1$$ is actually the definition of $\rho$. The follow-up question was to show that
$$\rho = \inf \left\{\lambda>0 : \sum |a_n|^{-\lambda}<+\infty\right\}\tag2$$
Obviously, we need $|a_n|\to\infty$ to have a chance of the series $\sum |a_n|^{-\lambda}$ converging (and of $\rho$ being finite). Since we are dealing with series of nonnegative terms, convergence is not affected by rearranging the series so that $|a_n|$ is increasing. Now (1) can be rewritten as 
$$\rho=\limsup_{n\to\infty } \frac{\log n}{\log |a_n|}\tag3$$
If $\lambda>\rho$, then $\log|a_n|>(\lambda-\epsilon)^{-1}\log n$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and all sufficiently large $n$. Hence $$|a_n|^{-\lambda}=\exp(-\lambda \log|a_n|)<\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\epsilon}n\right) = n^{-\lambda/(\lambda-\epsilon)}\tag4$$ and the series $\sum |a_n|^{-\lambda}$ converges.

If $\lambda<\rho$, then $\log|a_n|<(\lambda+\epsilon)^{-1}\log n$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and infinitely many values of $n$. Hence $$|a_n|^{-\lambda}=\exp(-\lambda \log|a_n|)>\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\epsilon}n\right) = n^{-\lambda/(\lambda+\epsilon)}\tag5$$ Since the terms of $\sum |a_k|^{-\lambda}$ are decreasing, for $n$ as above we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^{-\lambda} \ge n |a_n|^{-\lambda} =n^{\epsilon/(\lambda+\epsilon)}\tag6$$ hence the series diverges.